# Accessing a 2D array in C but no column index

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, compiler-errors, garbage

if i have a 2D array

`int A[3][2] = { {3,4}, {5,6}, {0,-5} }`

what will be the result if I try to print the element A[1]? will it be garbage value? or will it become a logical error?

Comment: Technically C doesn't have multi-dimensional array. What you have with `A` is an array  *of arrays* of `int`. So `A[1]` is an array (of two `int` values). If the compiler will complain or if it's a logical error depends on the context, what you do with the array.

Comment: so if I try to print the value of A[1], what would be the result of it? garbage?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, technically C does not have negative numbers but only *unary minus* followed by numerical literal

Comment: @TerryTan, it depends on *how* you try to print it.  There are ways that would produce perfectly valid, well-defined results, and ways that would produce undefined behavior.

Comment: Note also that the program producing undefined behavior does not necessarily mean it would yield output that you would recognize as "garbage".

Comment: `T[1]` would be a valid object of type `int[2]` that will likely decay  (in most contexts) to a pointer to element `T[1][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do something like

```
printf("%d\n", A[1]);
```

then that will be *undefined behavior*. That's because the array `A[1]` will decay to a *pointer* to its first element (i.e. in that context `A[1]` will decay to `&A[1][0]`), and the `%d` format specifier is wrong for printing pointers.

However

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) A[1]);
```

will be perfectly fine, as `%p` is the correct format specifier to print `void *` pointers.

---

And as noted in a comment, just because you have undefined behavior that doesn't mean the program will crash or result it "garbage" (even though the (possibly truncated) pointer might look like that when printed as a decimal integer).